# Can't Require Node Modules In WebWorker (NWJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, node-webkit, web-worker

I'm trying to do something I thought would be simple. I'm using nwjs (Formerly called Node-Webkit) which if you don't know basically means I'm developing a desktop app using Chromium & Node where the DOM is in the same scope as Node. I want to offload work to a webworker so that the GUI doesn't hang when I send some text off to Ivona Cloud (using ivona-node) which is a text to speech API. The audio comes back in chunks as it's generated and gets written to an MP3. ivona-node uses fs to write the mp3 to the drive. I got it working in the dom but webworkers are needed to not hang the UI. So I have two node modules I need to use in the webworker, ivona-node and fs.

The problem is that in a webworker you can't use require. So I tried packaging ivona-node and fs with browserify (There's a package called browserify-fs for this which I used) and replacing require with importScripts(). Now I'm getting var errors in the node modules.

Note: I don't think the method of native_fs_ will work for writing the mp3 to disk in chunks (The stream) as it should be and I'm getting errors in the Ivona package as well (Actually first and foremost) that I don't know how to fix. I'm including all information to reproduce this.

Here's an error I'm getting in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var VM39 ivonabundle.js:23132

- Steps to reproduce in NWJS:

npm install ivona-node

npm install browserify-fs

npm install -g browserify

- Now I browserified main.js for ivona-node and index.js for browserify-fs:

browserify main.js > ivonabundle.js

browserify index.js > fsbundle.js

---

package.json...

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "description": "appdescr",
  "title": "apptitle",
  "main": "index.html",
  "window":
  {
    "toolbar": true,
    "resizable": false,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500
  },
  "webkit":
  {
    "plugin": true
  }
}
```

index.html...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>apptitle</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><output id="result"></output></p>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button>
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>
<br><br>

<script>
    var w;

    function startWorker() {
        if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
            if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
                w = new Worker("TTMP3.worker.js");
                w.postMessage(['This is some text to speak.']);
            }
            w.onmessage = function(event) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
            };
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
        }
    }

    function stopWorker() {
        w.terminate();
        w = undefined;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

TTMP3.worker.js...

```
importScripts('node_modules/browserify-fs/fsbundle.js','node_modules/ivona-node/src/ivonabundle.js');
onmessage = function T2MP3(Text2Speak)
{
postMessage(Text2Speak.data[0]);
//var fs = require('fs'),

//    Ivona = require('ivona-node');

var ivona = new Ivona({
    accessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    secretKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
});

//ivona.listVoices()
//.on('end', function(voices) {
//console.log(voices);
//});

//  ivona.createVoice(text, config)
//  [string] text - the text to be spoken
//  [object] config (optional) - override Ivona request via 'body' value
ivona.createVoice(Text2Speak.data[0], {
    body: {
        voice: {
            name: 'Salli',
            language: 'en-US',
            gender: 'Female'
        }
    }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('text.mp3'));
postMessage("Done");
}
```

Comment: do you have to save it to the disk? you can send the bin data from the worker to the top to save if you really need, but i don't see why it needs saved at all.

Comment: Maybe, but what about the errors I'm getting from ivona-node? I wasn't getting them in the dom, just in the webworker.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var      VM39 ivonabundle.js:23132

Comment: Why not use `require('child_process').fork`?

Comment: I don't want to load up a new instance of nwjs to do this one thing. that would be very expensive in resources.

Comment: Are you aware that `ivona-node` doesn't appear as a browserify-compatible module on npm? check this site: http://browserifysearch.org/

Comment: @xendi, I follow your example and actually I can use `ivona-node` and `browserify-fs` in the `web worker`, but I'm getting an `Uncaught Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.`  when try to save the stream. In my case was necessary to change one statement inside `ivone-node` in order to browserify it correctly (using this: `HttpsPA = require('./proxy');` instead of: `HttpsPA = require(__dirname +  '/proxy');` in `main.js` to load properly the `proxy` feature)

Comment: @leobelizquierdo I'll try that. Would you post that solution with source and if it works I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that I wan to point out first:

1. Including node modules in a web worker

In order to include the module `ivona-node` I had to change a little its code. When I try to browserify it I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules/ivona-node/src/proxy'`. Checking the `bundle.js` generated I notice that it doesn't include the code of the module `proxy` which is in the file `proxy.js` in the `src` folder of `ivona-node`. I can load the `proxy` module changing this line `HttpsPA = require(__dirname + '/proxy');` by this: `HttpsPA = require('./proxy');`. After that `ivona-node` can be loaded in the client side through `browserify`. Then I was facing another error when trying to follow the example. Turn out that this code:

```
ivona.createVoice(Text2Speak.data[0], {
    body: {
        voice: {
            name: 'Salli',
            language: 'en-US',
            gender: 'Female'
        }
    }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('text.mp3'));
```

is no longer correct, it cause the error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.` The problem here is in the module `http`. the module `browserify` has wrapped many built-in modules of `npm`, which mean that  they are available when you use `require()` or use their functionality. `http` is one of them, but as you can reference here: [strem-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-http), It tries to match node's api and behavior as closely as possible, but some features aren't available, since browsers don't give nearly as much control over requests. Very significant is the fact of the class `http.ClientRequest`, this class in `nodejs` environment create an `OutgoingMessage` that produce this statement `Stream.call(this)` allowing the use of the method `pipe` in the request, but in the `browserify` version when you call `https.request` the result is a `Writable` Stream, this is the call inside the `ClientRequest`: `stream.Writable.call(self)`. So we have explicitly a `WritableStream` even with this method:

```
Writable.prototype.pipe = function() {
  this.emit('error', new Error('Cannot pipe. Not readable.'));
};
```

The responsible of the above error. Now we have to use a different approach to save the data from `ivona-node`, which leave me to the second issue.

2. Create a file from a web worker

Is well know that having access to the FileSystem from a web application have many security issues, so the problem is how we can have access to the FileSystem from the web worker. One first approach is using the HTML5 [FileSystem API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html). This approach has the inconvenient that it operate in a sandbox, so if we have in a desktop app we want to have access to the OS FileSystem. To accomplish this goal we can pass the data from the web worker to the main thread where we can use all the `nodejs` FileSystem functionalities.  Web worker provide a functionality called `Transferable Objects`, you can get more info [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) and [here](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#transferable-objects) that we can use to pass the data received from the module `ivona-node` in the web worker to the main thread and then use `require('fs')` in the same way that `node-webkit` provide us.  These are the step you can follow:

1. install `browserify`

   ```
   npm install -g browserify
   ```
2. install `ivona-node`

   ```
   npm install ivona-node --save
   ```
3. go to `node_modules/ivona-node/src/main.js` and change this line:

   `HttpsPA = require(__dirname + '/proxy');`

   by this:

   `HttpsPA = require('./proxy');`
4. create your `bundle.js`.

   Here you have some alternatives, create a `bundle.js` to allow a `require()`  or put some code in a file with some logic of what you want (you can actually include all the code of the web worker) and then create the `bundle.js`. In this example I will create the `bundle.js` only for have access to `require()` and use `importScripts()` in the web worker file

   `browserify -r ivona-node > ibundle.js`
5. Put all together

   Modify the code of the web worker and `index.html` in order to receive the data in the web worker and send it to the main thread (in index.html)

this is the code of web worker (MyWorker.js)

```
importScripts('ibundle.js');
var Ivona = require('ivona-node');

onmessage = function T2MP3(Text2Speak)
{
    var ivona = new Ivona({
        accessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secretKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });

    var req = ivona.createVoice(Text2Speak.data[0], {
        body: {
            voice: {
                name: 'Salli',
                language: 'en-US',
                gender: 'Female'
            }
        }
    });

    req.on('data', function(chunk){
        var arr = new Uint8Array(chunk);
        postMessage({event: 'data', data: arr}, [arr.buffer]);
    });

    req.on('end', function(){
        postMessage(Text2Speak.data[0]);
    });

}
```

and index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>apptitle</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><output id="result"></output></p>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button>
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>
<br><br>

<script>
    var w;
    var fs = require('fs');

    function startWorker() {
        var writer = fs.createWriteStream('text.mp3');
        if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
            if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
                w = new Worker("MyWorker.js");

                w.postMessage(['This is some text to speak.']);
            }
            w.onmessage = function(event) {
                var data = event.data;
                if(data.event !== undefined && data.event == 'data'){
                     var buffer = new Buffer(data.data);
                     writer.write(buffer);
                }
                else{
                    writer.end();
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
                }

            };
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
        }
    }

    function stopWorker() {
        w.terminate();
        w = undefined;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```